# Question regarding image tiling in a QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, image, qt, qt4

This is related to one of my other questions.

If I am tiling a large image by creating a separate QGraphicsItem (with the raster data as its pixmap), how do I keep track of the QGraphicsItem's position within the scene? Obviously for raster data, it is important to keep all the tiles "touching" to make a continuous image and they also have to be in the right place so the image doesnt look jumbled.

Does each tile have to have positioning methods that move it in relation to it's neighbors on the top/left/bottom/right? This seems kind of clunky. Is there a better way to make them all move together?

In other words, if I pan the scene with scroll bars, or pick up the image and drag/move it around in the scene, I want all the tiles to also move and stay in the right position relative to each other.

What is the best approach for controlling the layout, which tiles need to be rendered (i.e. only the visible ones), and populating the data only once it is needed? Also, once a tile has been rendered, is the data from it ever dropped, and repopulated from the image file, say if it stays out of view for a while, then comes back later if someone pans to that section?

Answer (score 1):

There are (more than) 2 ways of doing this:

1. Use [QGraphicsItemGroup](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsitemgroup.html) which
   handles grouping of your tile items
   for you. It moves, selects, updates
   it's group members as if they are
   one. I've never used it but from the
   doc, it seems to work with typical
   applications.
2. Paint the tiles yourself in the
   paint() of one custom item. This
   gives you total control on how to
   place and draw the tiles while the
   item truly acts as one item since it
   is, well, one item. This is what I
   do.

Comment: I was hoping you would answer, figuring you had done this sort of thing before. Can you give me some idea of what I would do if I was going to override the paint() method of my already-customized QGraphicsItem? It is a little unclear to me for example, how I would tell paint to ONLY paint stuff visible in my viewer, how to do the positioning, etc in the painter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951072/using-qtconcurrent-to-load-a-pixmap-and-paint-it this is a helpful thread I have been looking at, but it is implemented using a group of QGraphicsItems instead of one. Whern you are talking about using a single QGI, do you mean to literally only use a single QGI, or to make some sort of "tile QGI" like is mentioned in the link, and paint those QGI tiles from the paint of the parent item? if so, doesnt seem much different from the group way of doing things?

Comment: The main reason I am asking about some of these things - if you'll recall, my current custom Pixmap item has the functionality that allows you to scale an item while mousing over it. I guess if I did have a bunch of these together in a tile, I could detect with this.group() and if it existed, pass the zooming to the QGraphicsItemGroup that would presumably scale them in and out without adjusting the position, right?